# Stack can't find a downloaded module (Data.MultiSet)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've been using stack (in my linux computer) to compile my haskell code and today I installed for the first time an external module. I installed Data.MultiSet by running the following command:

> sudo stack install multiset

Supposedly the module was succesfully installed but I can't load it, stack throws the following message when I try to compile my code:

> ..error: Could not find module ‘Data.MultiSet’...

I checked the files contained in my .stack directory and there are many files with the name of this package but I am not very familiar with this directory tree. I also tried writing the name of the module in the dependency field of the package.yaml of my project but it didn't work either. Any clues of what's happening? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a `--package multiset` option to your command e.g. `stack ghc --package multiset myfile.hs`. Not putting this as an answer as I don’t know exactly which command you’re using for compilation. (Also, [`stack install` is discouraged](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/02/10/an-opinionated-guide-to-haskell-in-2018/#understanding-stacks-model-and-avoiding-its-biggest-gotcha), especially for libraries.)

Comment: @bradrn I think that comment could be expanded into a great answer.

Comment: Thanks @leftaroundabout! Which bits do you think could be expanded?

Comment: It should quote the important parts from the article you've linked to.

Comment: @leftaroundabout But that isn’t really related to the question — it’s just tangential information which I thought was important enough to warrant a mention.

Comment: @bradrn I think it's not so tangential, but if you think... I wrote an answer now.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I _really_ like that answer! I knew everything in it already, but the way you wrote it (and the first paragraph in particular) really gave me a different viewpoint on what Stack offers.

Answer (score 2):

Stack doesn't work like that. The idea behind Stack is this: you have a *project*, you know the dependencies of this project, and Stack ensures you can always build that project – now or in the future. Stack is *not* about tweaking your system in some way that'll give you access to some packages here and now.

So, *if* you're going to use Stack for development (which I personally don't, but I also don't say it's a bad idea; lots Haskellers do this) then you should first set up the file you're working on as part of a project. This can be as simple as making your file a *Stack snippet*: add the following to the top of your file (I'll assume it's called `script.hs`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-13.0 --install-ghc
      runghc --package multiset
  -}
```

(You could also pass those flags on the command line for `stack`, but that gets tedious quickly. `env` really does nothing else, but consistently.)

Then make your file *executable* – on Linux or OSX this can be done with `chmod +x script.hs` – and all you need to do to compile & run that script will be `./script.hs`. (*Not* `stack script.hs` or `ghc script.hs`.) The great thing about this is that you get “instant continuous integration”: if Stack is able to build run your script on your computer now, you can be pretty sure that it'll also work on any other computer in the future, without you needing to remember what packages to install etc..

More info on that technique: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/08/bitrot-free-scripts.

If it's more than a simple script you're writing, you should make a proper Cabal/Stack configuration for it. This can be created easily with `cabal init` (regardless of whether you will use Cabal or Stack).

Comment: Thanks! I actually don't want to make a script but the information about scripting you just provided is pretty useful either way. I am downloading problems from the internet and writing the "solution" just to become better at the language. So, what do you think, should I keep using stack or start to use Cabal mainly? And I know you don't use Stack but do you think that installing the package might cause a problem?

Comment: As I said I use Cabal. With that you _can_ install packages and then have them available directly from anywhere on your computer. But, this is kind of a deprecated workflow (even within Cabal). So if you're using Stack now, maybe best stick to it.

Comment: @SirMaik For an alternate viewpoint, I use `stack` extensively, and find it to be amazing. At the moment Stack and Cabal are roughly at feature parity, but I _really_ like the way Stack emphasises reproducible builds; that is, the feature that the same file/project will build the same way on any computer. And I think it’s worth noting that Stack can also install packages into the global context like Cabal does; every now and again I run `stack build interestingPackageName` to get access to it in e.g. GHCi. It’s not recommended but it’s certainly possible!